# R force bar colours

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

I am a beginner and self-taught R user so bear with me.

My data looks something like this:

```
   city variable value
    a   var1    0.398847367
    a   var2    0.975311071
    a   var3    0.957249734
    b   var1    0.313723366
    b   var2    0.130885548
    b   var3    0.771616001
    c   var1    0.057720637
    c   var2    0.398434369
    c   var3    0.088653681
    d   var1    0.024273226
    d   var2    0.744307456
    d   var3    0.315222384
```

I am trying to make a stack bar plot with ggplot. The order of the colours is very important. 
My code is

```
cols <- c(var1="tomato2", var2="steelblue3", var2="darkolivegreen3")

ggplot(LUL4, aes(x=city, y=value, group=factor(variable)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") +  
   scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
```

Doing this I don't get the colours I selected in the object `cols`. I have tried to avoid `cols` and paste `scale_fill_manual(values =values = c("darkolivegreen3", "tomato2", "steelblue3"))` in the first line of the code, right after the `geom_bar` command. Still it doesn't work and I am out of ideas. Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: You need one more closing bracket on the first line (though that won't fix your problem).

Comment: As you'll see in my answer, only the first 3 lines of code are necessary. Try not to include slabs of extraneous code - it just makes it hard to read, and introduces other, unrelated errors. This is particularly true if you refer to objects (e.g. `LUL2`, `dollar`) that we don't know anything about.

Comment: Sorry, I will take these comments into considerations for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks jbaums, although I wanted them stacked. In any case, adding `aes(fill= VARIABLENAME)` in the `geom_bar` options was the key to make `scale_fill_manual` work. Thanks!

The solution that I had in mind is the one below where the bars are also stacked. Hope it helps!

```
d <- read.table(text='city variable value
    a   var1    0.398847367
    a   var2    0.975311071
    a   var3    0.957249734
    b   var1    0.313723366
    b   var2    0.130885548
    b   var3    0.771616001
    c   var1    0.057720637
    c   var2    0.398434369
    c   var3    0.088653681
    d   var1    0.024273226
    d   var2    0.744307456
    d   var3    0.315222384', header=T)

cols <- c('violetred3', 'palegreen4', 'orangered')

ggplot(d, aes(x=city, y=value, fill=factor(variable))) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") 

ggplot(d, aes(x=city, y=value, group=factor(variable))) + geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", aes(fill=variable)) + scale_fill_manual(values=cols)
```

Comment: I see that now... sorry :/
Have edited

Answer (score 1):

The [`ggplot2` docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) are a great resource - use them :)

If you specify a `fill` aesthetic for `geom_bar`, then `scale_fill_manual` will work as you hoped.

```
d <- read.table(text='city variable value
    a   var1    0.398847367
    a   var2    0.975311071
    a   var3    0.957249734
    b   var1    0.313723366
    b   var2    0.130885548
    b   var3    0.771616001
    c   var1    0.057720637
    c   var2    0.398434369
    c   var3    0.088653681
    d   var1    0.024273226
    d   var2    0.744307456
    d   var3    0.315222384', header=T)

cols <- c(var1="tomato2", var2="steelblue3", var2="darkolivegreen3")
```

**[EDIT - OP pointed out that I had misread the Q]**

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=city, y=value, group=factor(variable))) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=variable)) +  
       scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

[image: corrected plot]